# Difference between asdf vs bundler

Tags: ruby, bundler, asdf

What is the difference between [asdf](http://asdf-vm.com) and [bundler](https://bundler.io)?

`asdf` docs states that "it is a tool that can manage multiple language runtime versions on a per-project basis."

`bundler` states that it "provides a consistent environment for Ruby projects by tracking and installing the exact gems and versions that are needed."

Is the difference the same as `pyenv` vs `poetry` for Python projects?

I can't grasp the difference and the need for both to be used in the same project. I may be missing the main difference between version vs dependency management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`asdf` is used to manage different versions of the used *programming languages*.  In the context of Ruby projects, it is used to decide if you want to run your project with, for example, Ruby `2.7.4`, Ruby `3.0.3`, or Ruby `3.1.1`. Using such a ruby version manager (like `asdf`, `rbenv`, `rvm`) is extremely useful when you work on different Ruby projects at the same time and they depend on different Ruby versions or when you are in the process of upgrading a Ruby project to a newer version and you need to switch between versions a lot. Additionally, when checking in the Ruby configuration into your version control system you can make sure that all developers use the same versions.

`bundler` on the other hand is used to define *library dependencies* of your application. Imagine your Ruby application uses the `redis` gem to connect to a Redis database, then you can use bundler to define what version of the `redis` gem you want to use in your application. This is important because different versions might have different APIs or only newer versions support required features, or a new version introduced a breaking change that your application is not able to handle yet. Additionally, `bundler` helps to solve nested dependencies, like, when your app depends on gems a and b, but those gems also depend on gem c but with slightly different requirements. Then `bundler` tries to find a version of the c gem that fulfills the dependency config of both gems a and b.

Is the difference the same as `pyenv` vs `poetry` for Python projects? I am not familiar with the Python ecosystem. But from having a glance at the docs of `pyenv` vs `poetry` IMHO they solve a similar requirement.